# Auto close math mode braces in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I use VS code with `LateX workshop` extension. Is there any way to auto close inline math mode `\(\)` and math mode `\[\]` in VS Code?

The following image is from Overleaf. This is the behavior I am trying to get on VS code.

[image]

Comment: you should read https://stackoverflow.com/q/62199950/11107541