# dollar sign autocompletion in latex

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, editor, settings

For auto-pairing the dollar sign `$` in `*.tex` files, I added

```
  [
    "$",
    "$"
  ],
```

to the file `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/latex/latex-language-configuration` under `autoClosingPairs`. Then the autocomplete works.

However, once I enable any of the following `LaTex` extensions, `LaTex`, `LaTex language support`, `LaTex Workshop`, the autocomplete **stops working**.

I wonder how to keep the autocomplete functionality while enabling the extensions?

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/62199950/11107541